# How to remove external JS when navigate to another page VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

I have java script component in home component with external js. I need to remove external js when page navigate to another page. Page does not refresh.

```
<script>
  function initFreshChat() {
    window.fcWidget.init({
      token: "***",
      host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com"
    });
  }
  function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
</script>
```

This is the external js: https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js

I need this because i need to keep this freshchat window in one page.
This can be done by putting any condition. But it will works if we refresh the page. Here pages are not refreshing at all.
Therefore I need to remove the external js when navigate to another pages. And mount back when came to this page.

Comment: try this ` <script scoped>` instead of `<script>`

Comment: its not work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the script in side a Vue component life circle,

- render
- remove
- refresh

whenever you need.

I found this code on codepen https://codepen.io/akccakcctw/pen/LBKQZE

```js
Vue.component("fc-button", {
template: "#fcButton",
props: {
 fc: {
   type: Object,
   default: {},
 }
 
},
methods: {
 openWidget: function() {
   document.getElementById("fc_frame").style.visibility = "visible";
   window.fcWidget.open();
 }
}
});

const vm = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: function() {
 return {
   fc: {
     isInit: false,
   },
 };
},
mounted: function() {
 var self = this;
 window.fcSettings = {
   token: "8d3a4a04-5562-4f59-8f66-f84a269897a1",
   host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
   config: {
     cssNames: {
       widget: "custom_fc_frame",
       open: "custom_fc_open",
       expanded: "custom_fc_expanded"
     },
     headerProperty: {
       hideChatButton: true
     }
   },
   onInit: function() {
     
     window.fcWidget.on("widget:loaded", function() {
       self.fc.isInit = true;
       window.fcWidget.on("unreadCount:notify", function(resp) {
         console.log(resp);
         test = resp;
         if (resp.count > 0) {
           // document.getElementById('notify').classList.add('h-btn-notify');
           document.getElementById("notify").style.visibility = "visible";
         } else if (resp.count == 0) {
           // document.getElementById('notify').classList.remove('h-btn-notify');
           document.getElementById("notify").style.visibility = "hidden";
         }
       });
       window.fcWidget.on("widget:closed", function() {
         document.getElementById("fc_frame").style.visibility = "hidden";
         document.getElementById("open_fc_widget").style.visibility =
           "visible";
       });
       window.fcWidget.on("widget:opened", function(resp) {
         document.getElementById("open_fc_widget").style.visibility =
           "hidden";
       });
     });
   }
 };
}
});
```

Comment: I followed this code. Its does not use freshchat button. It uses alternate button and trigger the freshchat window. This is totally works for me. But need to bit re-work before use this for actual VueJS project. Thank you very much for your support! :)

Comment: hi @rian my code is working fine on localhost now. But its not clickable initially page load on production. If I refresh the page it works.

Comment: I solved the issue with replacing 'async' with 'defer' keyword inside external js script tag.